# Crash when adding a property on Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, properties, sprite-kit, runtime-error

I've been trying to know where my Sprite Kit game was crashing because it gave me this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Attemped to add nil node', reason: 'Attemped to add nil node to parent: <SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}'
```

And I think that this problem happens when adding a property so I ask how to add a property ( a SKLabelNode in this case) correctly. This is the way I do it:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;
```

But the game crashes with this code.
Please can anybody help me, I will appreciate. Thanks

Comment: The exception message tells you what you did wrong - you tried to add a child node that is nil.  This isn't how you store the property, but rather how you alloc/initialise the node (or in this case you probably didn't).  You should set an exception breakpoint to identify the line where the exception is occurring.  Also, you should use "strong" rather than "retain" in property definitions with ARC.

Comment: Thank you! Now I initialize the node with `alloc` and `init` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message tells you what you did wrong - you tried to add a child node that is nil. This isn't how you store the property, but rather how you alloc/initialise the node (or in this case you probably didn't).

Also, you should use `strong` rather than `retain` in property definitions with ARC.